# Randomly select index of matrix exactly once

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix, vector, random

I have a matrix of 1's (just a 2D vector of ints) and I am trying to randomly select an index so that I can turn that 1 to a 0. My goal is to select every index of the matrix exactly once so that after running a for loop with exactly as many iterations as there are indices, the matrix will be filled with 0s (the 0 doesn't actually matter, the number that replaces the 1 and the 1 itself are arbitrary).

My current approach is very slow. It has been to run a while loop that checks each pass to see if there are still any 1's left. This is obviously incredibly inefficient, but I am not sure how to do this only once for each index and ensure there are no repeats so that I can change to a for loop. Any advice would be very helpful!

Comment: Create an array filled with each index of the matrix, shuffle that array, iterate over the array changing each index in the matrix to a 0.

Comment: Doin' the Fisher-Yates Shuffle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just generate a random sequence of the matrix indices as @Jonny mentioned in the comment. Then iterate through each element of this sequence. The following is a Java implementation I just wrote in case it helps:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Test {

    public static void randomSelectMatrixIndex(int[][] matrix) {
        int rows = matrix.length;
        int cols = matrix[0].length;
        int[] indices = new int[rows*cols];
        System.out.println("Index array before shuffle: ");
        for (int i=0; i<indices.length; i++) {
            indices[i] = i;
            System.out.print(i+" ");            
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        shuffle(indices);

        System.out.println("Index array after shuffle: ");
        for (int j=0; j<indices.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(indices[j]+" ");
            matrix[indices[j]/cols][indices[j]%cols] = 0;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static void shuffle(int[] indices) {
        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i=indices.length; i>0; i--) {
            int randomIndex = ran.nextInt(i);
            int temp = indices[i-1];
            indices[i-1] = indices[randomIndex];
            indices[randomIndex] = temp;
        }
    }

    private static void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int[][] matrix = {{1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1,1}};

        System.out.println("Matrix before random select: ");
        printMatrix(matrix);
        System.out.println();

        randomSelectMatrixIndex(matrix);

        System.out.println("Matrix after random select: ");
        printMatrix(matrix);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use this algorithm, which is a bit more efficient, although still not very efficient after a lot of iterations (note that for best result, use a evenly distributed random number generator):

```
select random index -> check if 1
  |                    |        |
  |      repeat        |False   |True
  |--------------------|        |--Change value at index to 0
                                           |
                                           |
                                        the end
```

I wonder if there is something one could change to make it more efficient...

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Create a vector of pointers using nested loops so that there's a pointer to every single element in the matrix. Randomly select a pointer. Change value to 0. Remove pointer from vector. Repeat until vector is empty. Matrix is now empty.

Comment: To remove the pointer from the vector, you can simply swap it with the one at the end of the vector and then resize the vector; this is faster than erasing from the middle. But at that point you've nearly implemented a shuffle, and the shuffle is simpler.